# Forcing async-await IProgress<T>.Report() to be synchronous

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm using **Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)** for some long task, using `IProgress<T>` to report progress to main UI.
The `Progress.Report` seems to work only if it is preceded by another await task. 
If i use in an inline for loop, for example, reports messages are posted only at the end of the task:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomething(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    progress.Report("Start");  // works
    await SomeTask();

    progress.Report("Message 1"); // works ONLY at end

    for ()
    {
        progress.Report("Message x"); // works ONLY at end
        // do some tasks inline
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is there some way to force Report messages to be posted synchronously?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "works ONLY at end"?

Comment: If you want `SomeTask` to report progress then it should have a `IProgress<string>` parameter and report progress normally via  `progress.Report`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Progress.Report seems to work only if it is preceded by another await task.

That makes sense. `Progress<T>` captures the `SynchronizationContext` and posts to it once you invoke the `Report` method. If you're async method isn't really async and has mostly CPU work that is done on the UI thread, you're not freeing the message loop to process more events, hence you're only seeing it update at the end of the method call.

This is how `Progress<T>.Report` is implemented:

```
protected virtual void OnReport(T value)
{
        // If there's no handler, don't bother going through the [....] context.
        // Inside the callback, we'll need to check again, in case 
        // an event handler is removed between now and then.
        Action<T> handler = m_handler;
        EventHandler<T> changedEvent = ProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null || changedEvent != null)
        {
            // Post the processing to the [....] context.
            // (If T is a value type, it will get boxed here.)
            m_synchronizationContext.Post(m_invokeHandlers, value);
        }
}
```

In order to remain responsive, you can offload the `for` loop to a threadpool thread:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    progress.Report("Start");  // works
    await SomeTask();
    progress.Report("Message 1");

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        progress.Report("Message x");
        // Do more CPU bound work
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: so i need to call in the for loop other await tasks?

Comment: @kim You need to free the UI thread to allow it to update. If you don't actually have any async work to do, you can do your other CPU bound work on a thread-pool thread using `Task.Run` so you don't end up freezing the UI

Comment: That `for` loop is non blocking?

Comment: Thank you. Task.Run was the solution.